# Arduino serial.print() is adding an extra character after the actual char

Tags: c, string, buffer, arduino, printf

```
        char *feedtime = "0:0";
        String interval = "6";

    char* convert(char* x, String y){

             int hour;
             int minute;


             sscanf(x, "%d:%d", &hour, &minute);

             char buf[5];

             if (y == "6"){

                 if (hour > 17){

                     hour = (hour+6)%24;

                     snprintf(buf, 5, "%d%s", hour, ":0");

                 }

                 if (hour < 18){

                   hour = hour + 6;
                   snprintf(buf, 5, "%d%s", hour, ":0\0");

                 }

             }

             buf [5] = '\0';
             return buf;
}
```

When I execute convert(time, interval);

the serial monitor returns the correct value but adds a ' or another symbol to it.

Any ideas why?

I updated my code from what people said, however I still get the same issue?

Comment: You did not fix the problem in jcopenha's answer.  It would help us be more constructive if you would show us the code that calls convert() and uses the result.

Comment: You need some constants -- get rid of magic numbers.  Specifically, if you declare your buffer to be 5 bytes, that means you can address 0-4.  `buf[5] = '\0'` is writing to memory you don't own.

Answer (score 3):

You are returning a pointer to a stack variable.  This is wrong.  Once the function exits the stack space used by 'buf' is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You need an extra character in your buffer.  You only have a 4 character array, but you need 5 characters (2 for the hour, 2 for the :0, and 1 for the trailing 0).  You also need to null terminate the string when you are done.

and what jcopenha says.

Comment: I increased the buffer size to 5, to null terminate the string how would I go about that and I'm suppose to null terminate buff?

Comment: Wouldn't the buf size change depending on the number of hour for example if hour is only one digit wouldn't the buf only need size 4 one for the our, two for :0 and one for the null?

Comment: Just declare buf to have 5 characters and change your snprintf argument to 5.  snprintf will put the null termination in automatically if there is space for it.

Answer (score 0):

Your strings aren't properly zeroterminated. Increase the size of buf.

Comment: buf [5] = '\0';

Would that null terminate my string?

Comment: Yes, if you make room for it.